# How to use pipe and fork

Tags: c, posix

I have the following code(there's a bunch of extra headers that were used in other parts of the code that I removed since they don't have anything to do with my issue). I have also removed the error checking for fork and pipe for brevity:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

void compile(char *fullname)
{
    int pid = fork();

    int pipe_send_output[2];
    pipe(pipe_send_output);

    if (pid == 0)
    {
        close(pipe_send_output[0]);
        dup2(pipe_send_output[1], STDERR_FILENO); // redirect output of gcc to the pipe
        execlp("gcc", "gcc", "-Wall", fullname, NULL);
        printf("execlp error");
    }
    else
    {
        close(pipe_send_output[1]);
        dup2(STDIN_FILENO, pipe_send_output[0]); // redirect from pipe to stdin
        close(pipe_send_output[0]);
        exit(0);
    }
}
int main(){
    compile("folder/small.c");
}
```

The compile function is supposed to create a new process which compiles some c file using gcc, and then sends the output(errors and warnings) to the parent process, to be printed. To do this I redirected STDERR to the write end of the pipe, and then in the parent process redirected the read end to stdin. I can't for the life of me figure out why it's not displaying anything. If I remove the redirection of stderr to the pipe, then plenty of stuff it outputed, so the issue isn't gcc not outputting anything. I tried to replace the redirection to stdin with reading from the pipe and then printing it, but that has the same result. A couple of time this did print one or 2 characters, which is even more confusing. This is the code that replaces the second call to dup2 for printing:

```
char buffer[1024];
while(read(pipe_send_output[0], buffer, 1024)) printf("%s", buffer);
```

I've looked everywhere on google and on the man page and still don't have a clue what's wrong.

Disclaimer:This is part of a project for a lab at university. The code that I wrote follows the blueprint from the materials my professor provided, and makes perfect sense to me. Any hint on what the issue may be is appreciated.

Comment: First call `pipe` then `fork`, not the opposite.

Comment: Bloody hell I can't believe that was the issue. Thank you so much!